# How can I shift the positions of even-numbered columns with a variable column responsive layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have a problem with css. I need to display a list of items with variable height within columns. Every second column should be shifted down:[image: Layout to be don]

The whole thing should be responsive therefore the html should be rather simple list.

What I tried is flex, but did not succeed for this problem, as well as column-count. With column-count, The display is closest, and I could add a padding to the top most item in the second column, however, since it must be responsive (different column count based on screen width), I need to select the first item in the second and fourth column which would solve the problem.

So if anyone has an idea how to solve this problem in css, I would be happy, It also would work when Javascript is involved, so if anyone can help me to select the topmost item in the second column, it would be appreciated as well.

html code:

```
<ul>
   <li>some content</li>
   <li>some content</li>
   <li>some content</li>
   <li>some content</li>
   <li>some content</li>
   <li>some content</li>
   etc.
</ul>
```

Comment: Off-topic: This doesn't seem like an appropriate use for a list.

Comment: @isherwood : How else would you propose to realise it?

Comment: Unless the content of your grid is actually list-type data, just use divs.

Comment: @isherwood: The number of items in the list is not known. However, it would be appreciated if you could help here with an code example.

Comment: I think we had a misunderstanding. You said, "Every second column should be shifted down". I think you meant that *the list item that happens to be at the top of every even column should be shifted down*. That's a different animal.

Comment: The critical point is whether the number of items in each column changes with screen size. Does it?

Comment: Yes, of coarse. If we have 20 items, we will have approx. 5 in each column in the 4 columns layout and 10 items in the 2 columns layout. (depending on the height of each element it could be 9 and 11 as well). Therefore I am not able to place the items individually in column divs (unless I do it with JS which would be the last possibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved with JS (Jquery):

- The list above is loaded into the DOM as a hidden element
- Using JS (Jquery), the content ist distributed into columns depending on the with of the window. (also with resize)
- The remaining job is done via CSS

Not nice, but seems to be the only solution.